# How to debug Clang plugin using lldb (or gdb)

Tags: clang, lldb

I want to debug Clang plugin.
However, I can't find informations about debugging of Clang plugin.
If you know how to debug Clang plugin, Could you tell me that information?
thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a small outline as i'm trying this myself atm. I am using lldb.

I am currently able to stop at any given function in the plugin but the source code is missing. It only shows the assembly.

When you invoke `clang` with `-Xclang -plugin (...)` it will fork into a child process. When invoking your plugin pass also the `-v` option to see the child process command line. Then use this command line in the debugger.

Original command line:

> ```
> $> clang++ -Xclang -load -Xclang ${PLUGIN} -Xclang -plugin -Xclang cgd -std=c++11 -w -fsyntax-only -v
> ```

should output:

> ```
> clang version 3.1 (tags/RELEASE_31/final 163510)
> Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> Thread model: posix
>  "/srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/clang-3.1" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -fsyntax-only -disable-free -main-file-name call_in_if.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1
> -fmodule-cache-path /var/tmp/clang-module-cache -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6
> -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu
> -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/backward
> -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include
> -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Werror -w -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro
> -fdebug-compilation-dir /srv/scratch/sigubufo/danceos_wd/clang/qtcreator-build -ferror-limit
> 19 -fmessage-length 205 -mstackrealign -fgnu-runtime
> -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -load lib/CallGraphDumper.so -plugin cgd -x c++ ../test_cases/call_in_if.cpp
> clang -cc1 version 3.1 based upon LLVM 3.1svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu
>  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/backward
>  /usr/local/include
>  /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include
>  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
>  /usr/include
> End of search list.
> ```

This is the part you need:

> ```
> "/srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/clang-3.1" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -fsyntax-only -disable-free -main-file-name call_in_if.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -fmodule-cache-path /var/tmp/clang-module-cache -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Werror -w -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /srv/scratch/sigubufo/danceos_wd/clang/qtcreator-build -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 205 -mstackrealign -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -load lib/CallGraphDumper.so -plugin cgd -x c++ ../test_cases/call_in_if.cpp
> ```

Now you invoke lldb with:

> ```
> lldb "/srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/clang-3.1"
> ```

And then in the lldb prompt you do

> ```
> (lldb) break set --name YourPlugin::FunctionToBreakAt
>
> (lldb) process launch -- -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -fsyntax-only -disable-free -main-file-name call_in_if.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1 -fmodule-cache-path /var/tmp/clang-module-cache -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.6/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /srv/scratch/sigubufo/clang/stable/3.1_src/build/bin/../lib/clang/3.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -Werror -w -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /srv/scratch/sigubufo/danceos_wd/clang/qtcreator-build -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 205 -mstackrealign -fgnu-runtime -fobjc-runtime-has-arc -fobjc-runtime-has-weak -fobjc-fragile-abi -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -load lib/CallGraphDumper.so -plugin cgd -x c++ ../test_cases/call_in_if.cpp
> ```

And that should work.

Comment: After testing clang 5.0, I can not confirm that loading a clang plugin will fork into a child process. Am I wrong or missing something?

Comment: `clang` is the master process (driver - gcc compatible flags). It runs `clang -cc1` (clang compiler frontend) as a child proc, which will dynamically load the plugin. "loading a clang plugin" will not fork by itself.