# Is there an equivalent of GDB for GCC for debugging when compiling with CLANG?

Tags: debugging, gcc, gdb, clang

I have found that you can debug with GDB when compiling with GCC however at our university we are required to use CLANG for compiling and I can't find an equivalent of GDB for GCC for CLANG, is there one?

Comment: Did you try using the same `gdb` as with gcc? Dwarf is a standard...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

LLDB appears to be the equivalent debugger for CLANG. Here are some links I found on learning LLDB and the equivalent commands for LLDB from GDB.

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

http://meowni.ca/posts/unscary-lldb/

[How to debug Clang plugin using lldb (or gdb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111982/how-to-debug-clang-plugin-using-lldb-or-gdb)

Answer (score 11):

You can use GDB or lldb with clang.

---

for example

```
$ clang hello.c -g
$ gdb a.out
```

Comment: The example in my edit worked for me, but I don't really know if that's what you are supposed to do.  I might just be trying out Cunningham's Law here.