# Protecting class memory array to detect segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, segmentation-fault

I am on Linux (CentOS 7.4, compiler Clang) and getting a segmentation fault (**not** easily reproducible) within a C++ struct object. This is a class member of a polymorphic object I do not allocate, but is instantiated within a framework I do not have the source code to. This means I cannot compile using sanitize easily and Valgrind increases the initialisation time from seconds to 5 minutes):

```
// C is allocated within a third party framework, I assume they use new()
//
class C : public ThirdPartyParentClass
{
    S s;
}

struct S
{
    .
    std::mutex   _mutex;
    .
};
```

the segmentation fault corrupts `_mutex`.

I therefore added a char buffer so I could see the corruption:

```
struct S
{
    .
    char         _buffer[1000];
    std::mutex   _mutex;
    .
};
```

and I can see the corrupted bytes when the segmentation fault occurs. However, I cannot determine *when* the corruption takes places.

To determine when the corruption takes place I would like to protect the char buffer bytes. I tried:

```
struct S
{
    S()
    {
        mprotect(&_buffer[0], 4096, PROT_NONE);
        const int test = buffer[0];  // Trigger seg fault to test it works
    }
    .
    char         _buffer[4096]__attribute__((aligned(4096)));
    std::mutex   _mutex;
    .
};
```

but my test to determine the memory protection is working, doesn't cause a seg fault.

Could somebody please help?

Comment: Detecting such problems is the purpose of *debugging*. Using a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a good start.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude tried but the problem is too infrequent and Valgrind increases the program load time from 2 seconds to 5 minutes (yes really).

Comment: No one said debugging is easy or quick. :) Is the program something which you or your customers are starting frequently and run only shortly? Or something which is started once and then run for a longer time (hours or days)? If it is started seldom and runs for a long time, using Valgrind might be worth it anyway.

Comment: Another way is to simply add a lot of logging to your program. Start out with a coarse and more overview logging, and use that to narrow down into smaller parts, where you then add more logging, until you can pinpoint the location where it happens. Or just add logging to all the places where the structure is used, before and after using the structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am the customer :) Yes totally understand debugging isn't quick/easy but the overhead of Valgrind would reduce the probability of it occurring (with the tradeoff of more information IF it did). Under typical usage the program is started and then left running for hours. I'm going to try and "inject" different data in to what I think the source is (courtesy of the char buffer) and then focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this at the source level is a bit silly. If you want to find the exact moment when something gets written to a particular memory address, use a data breakpoint (gcc calls them "watchpoints"). Just do `watch *(int*)0xWHATEVER` on the area of memory you expect to be corrupted, and it'll break on the first modification, with very low overhead.

Comment: Is this possible to do attaching GDB to the running process? I cannot start this under GDB as it's a module, part of a larger third party framework.

Comment: Yep, see the documentation.

Comment: And if you're using clang, I believe that lldb (which is the preferred debugger for clang, although gdb [probably works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659912/is-there-an-equivalent-of-gdb-for-gcc-for-debugging-when-compiling-with-clang)) can do the same things.